# Dataflow disable public ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, vpc

I´m using dataflow and I want to disable the public IP, I have tried the following commands:

```
--no_use_public_ips


 --disable-public-ips
```

I have also provided a subnetwork using the argument:

```
 --subnetwork regions/$REGION/subnetworks/default \
```

But nothing worked

Comment: Which language do you use? Did you specify a network in addition of a subnet? Do you perform calls to Google Cloud API or external API during your dataflow jobs?

Comment: I´m using python and using Google cloud Api.
I just specified the subnetwork

Comment: What's your error? Are you sure the subnet is in the correct region?

Comment: Yes, i confirmed it in vpc network, it´s us-east1 and have the name default

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i think I know what happend, I was passing one argument to dataflow that wasn´t correct, so no I have this message:
deploy-dataflow.sh: 102: --no_use_public_ips: not found

Comment: It seems like there might be a syntax error or incorrect argument passed in your script deploy-dataflow.sh. The error message indicates that something is wrong with the argument --no_use_public_ips.

Comment: I am using the option `--no_use_public_ips` as well, so the syntax is correct. I believe your `subnetwork` is incomplete - at least in my case, I use the complete string `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/MYPROJECT/regions/MYREGION/subnetworks/MYSUBNETWORK` (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#specify-subnet))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are working with a dataflow service and trying to disable public IPs. However, the options you mentioned `--no_use_public_ips` and `--disable-public-ips` don't seem to be standard options for Dataflow.

To disable public IPs for a Dataflow job, you typically need to ensure that your Dataflow workers are running in a private network. When you specify a subnetwork using the --subnetwork flag, it should be a private subnetwork that doesn't have external IP addresses.

You might want to change your subnetwork into this complete string: `--subnetwork https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/HOST_PROJECT_ID/regions/REGION_NAME/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK_NAME`

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future, since this question garnered a long thread.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.